# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have posted a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292581/login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon-in-sql-server-2008) few days back and provided its answer as well.

I am facing a strange issue, I have 2 servers first one is `dev` server and second is `QA`

When I execute the below line on `dev` server it works fine, but when I execute it on `QA`, it gives me the error `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'`, as I posted in my previous question.

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ‘sqlcmd -D db_name -S server_name -i sqlfile’
```

To resolve the above issue I have provided the username and pwd in the above query and it is working fine on both `DEV` and `QA` server. But to provide the username and pwd is not a nice approach as if we will change the server or pwd it directly impacts my query. So I want to execute the cmdshell command without using `username` and `pwd` on `QA` as well.

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing on `QA`. I have already provided the permissions to cmdshell on `QA`

**ANY QUICK HELP**

Comment: If you do no want to use user name password to run SQL cmd command. than on the QA server your windows login should be enabled. Please add your windows login on QA server so that the SQLCMD command login on QA DB server with your window login

Comment: @Harikant: If this is the reason then why it is executing fine on my DEV server, as I don't have windows Authentication enable there

Comment: where is your DEV Database? is not on your system, i guess? if yes that's why  your are able to do it.

Comment: @Harikant: Yes it is not on my system, and QA server is also not on my system, then what's the difference

Answer (score 0):

This is because the user the command runs as is `NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON`, and this login does not have access to the DB.

Consider this: everything must run under a user context. Every process needs a to have a windows user owning it.

The `SQLCMD` you are running - who is the windows user running it? it isn't you. It is the SQL Server service. (do some research on xp_cmdshell)

You first need to do some research on windows service accounts and understand what they are.

Then, some possible solutions:

A. Check what your QA SQL Server service is running as (in the logon tab in services.msc)
B. USe a linked server insteadm which can use `your` logon instead
C. You might also be able to use some kind of proxy (a windows user to override the SQL Service user just for this pupose) but I haven't investigated that.